# Pattern matching find pattern anywhere in list

Tags: python, pattern-matching, python-3.10

I have the following dictionary and I would like to get the value of `"msg"`, if the `"status"` is `"progress"`. The status `"progress"` or the key `"msg"` may or may not be in the dictionary, which is why I thought of using pattern matching to see if I can get what I want.

My attempt

```
my_dict = {
    "outer": [
        {"status": "to do", "desc": [{"msg": "foo"}]},
        {"status": "progress", "desc": [{"msg": "bar"}]},
        {"status": "done", "desc": [{"msg": "baz"}]},
    ]
}

match my_dict:
    case {'outer': [{'status': 'progress', 'desc': [{'msg': x}]}]}:
        print(x)
```

I am looking for something like `case {'outer': [*_, {'status': 'progress', 'desc': [{'msg': x}]}, *_]}:` but that does not work `SyntaxError: multiple starred names in sequence pattern`

Output I want (using pattern matching)

```
bar
```

I can get what I want with something like the following, but there are some checks I need to do make sure the key exists.

```
for i in my_dict['outer']: # check every status
    if i['status'] == 'progress': # check if the status is "progress"
        if 'desc' in i:
            for j in i['desc']: # loop the values of "desc"
                if 'msg' in j: # if the msg is there get the value
                    x = j['msg']
```

I want to know if there is a way to solve this using pattern matching, just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could do the following:

```
for info in my_dict["outer"]:
    match info:
        case {"status": "progress", "desc": [{"msg": msg}]}:
            print(msg)
            break
else:
    print("No Match")
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is guaranteed that the value `progress` will only occur once in `my_dict['outer']`, then you can pre-filter the list of items before match:

```
my_dict = {'outer': [{'status': 'to do', 'desc': [{'msg': 'foo'}]}, {'status': 'progress', 'desc': [{'msg': 'bar'}]}, {'status': 'done', 'desc': [{'msg': 'baz'}]}]}
match [i for i in my_dict['outer'] if i['status'] == 'progress']:
   case [{'status': _, 'desc': [{'msg': msg}]}]:
      print(msg)
```

Output:

```
'bar'
```